# Bash Shell Script Option Processing: Add -all and -q (quiet), Enforce No Repetition

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I've writing a Bash script that takes N options. Call them -1, -2, ..., -N. The following applies to use of the options:

- Any number of the options may be provided, from 0 - N
- No options take any arguments
- The options may be provided in any order

I process these in a rather standard way:

```
while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]
do
   OPTION="$1"

   case $OPTION in
      -1)
         process_option_1
         shift
         ;;
      -2)
         process_option_2
         shift
         ;;
      ...
      -N)
         process_option_N
         shift
         ;;
      *)
         echo "Unknown option $OPTION. Aborting..."
         exit 1
   esac
done
```

### GOAL 1

I'd like to add two additional options:

- **-all** This implies all of -1, -2, ... -N
- **-q** This denotes "quiet" mode, i.e. don't print anything to the display

If **-all** appears, it must appear either by itself or with **-q** only.

**-q** may be used with either the "**-all**" or the "-1 -2 ... -N" forms of invocation.

### GOAL 2

I'd like to enforce that no option may be repeated.

### QUESTION

I'm having a difficult time expanding my logic to meet my goals.

I'd like to ask the community: How may I meet these goals?

Please note that goal 2 is secondary. If somebody has a solution for goal 1 but not for goal 2, by all means, please provide it!

**Edited to add: I can brute-force the logic; what I mean to say is that I'm looking for a clean, elegant solution that doesn't involve needless repeated looping over the options, that provides automatic inclusion of the processing for new individual options into -all, etc...**

Answer (score 0):

I think this can work (didn't test it).

```
# Use flags to set options on or off.
opt_1=0
opt_2=0
opt_N=0
opt_q=0
all=0

# Goal 2, make options unique.
set -- $(echo $@|tr ' ' '\n'|sort -u)

# Test for -q option.
if [[ "$@" =~ -q ]]; then
opt_q=1
set -- $(echo ${@/-q/})
fi

# Goal 1, -q already processed if present, see if -all is alone.
if [[ "$@" =~ -all ]] && [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
echo -all only by itself or with -q
exit
fi

while [ -n "$1" ]; do
case "$1" in
-1)opt_1=1;;
-2)opt_2=1;;
-N)opt_N=1;;
-all)all=1;;
esac
shift
done

if [ "$opt_q" -eq 1 ]; then
exec 1>/dev/null 2>&1
fi

if [ "$opt_1" -eq 1 ] || [ "$all" -eq 1 ]; then
# do stuff for -1
fi

..etc..
```